# How can I create woocommerce coupon with an expiration date using the rest api?

Tags: date, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, restriction, coupon

I'm trying to create a coupon via the woocommerce rest api:
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-coupon

I can create coupons fine, but it seems the expiration date is always unset.

e.g. posting

```json
{
  "code": "IGNME",
  "description": "IGNORE ME",
  "discount_type": "percent",
  "amount": 5,
  "date_expires": "2024-03-21T19:23:00",
  "date_expires_gmt": "2024-03-21T18:23:00"
}
```

Would return;

```json
  ...
  "date_expires": null,
  "date_expires_gmt": null,
  ...
```

Checking on the site and there is no expiration date aswell. I tried date/time different formats but could not get a valid one.

How can I create woocommerce coupon with an expiration date using the rest api?

Comment: It looks like a bug… you should report that to WooCommerce devs, via the plugin support (or via GitHub).